# parse JSON response in android with multiple values

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting JSON response as the following string from a web page , I need to parse that response and store in Java array in android.

```
{"companyName":["Sanmar Group","Dcygnus Technocracy"]}
{"CampusDate":["25\/10\/2016","24\/10\/2016"]}
{"companyPackage":["3.67","1.8"]}
{"status":["your are not eligible","your are not eligible"]}
```

Comment: You json is invalid

Comment: Then is their any another way to retrieve the data from above format to java array.

Comment: First of all you server should send the proper json response, most probably there should be a comma between all those objects and you response should be a json array

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
var response = array('companyName'=>$companies,'CampusDate'=>$campdates,'companyPackage'=>$packages,'status'=>$status);
echo json_encode(response );
```

Comment: Please edit your other answer. This does not answer the question on its own

Comment: What happened @cricket_007

Comment: Looks like you posted this as an answer, rather than an edit, then the OP moved the accepted post from the other one to this one.

Comment: Does that above code  written for parsing adds all data in 'allComInfo'@Arfan Mirza

Comment: Yes.. as you asked java aaray.. si i put aal in array.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is correct json format with parser

```
///Start Php///

var response = array('companyName'=>$companies,'CampusDate'=>$campdates,'companyPackage'=>$packages,'status'=>$status);
echo json_encode(response );

///End Php///

{
    "companyName": ["Sanmar Group", "Dcygnus Technocracy"],
    "CampusDate": ["25/10/2016", "24/10/2016"],
    "companyPackage": ["3.67", "1.8"],
    "status": ["your are not eligible", "your are not eligible"]
}
```

//Class to hold all value of a company

```
class CompanyInfo {
    public String companyName;
    public String CampusDate;
    public String companyPackage;
    public String status;
}

//Json Parser
class CompanyParser {

    public ArrayList<CompanyInfo> allComInfo;

    public CompanyParser() {
        allComInfo = new ArrayList<CompanyInfo>();
    }

    public void parseJson(String jsonString) {
        try {
            JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            parseCompanyName(reader.getJSONArray("companyName"));
            parseCampusDate(reader.getJSONArray("CampusDate"));
            parseCompanyPackage(reader.getJSONArray("companyPackage"));
            parseStatus(reader.getJSONArray("status"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void checkAndAddNewEmptyCompnayAtIndex(int index) {
        if (index >= allComInfo.size()) {
            allComInfo.add(new CompanyInfo());
        }
        else if(allComInfo.get(index) == null){
            allComInfo.add(new CompanyInfo());
        }
    }

    private void parseCompanyName(JSONArray data) throws JSONException {
        int size = data.length();
        for (int ak = 0; ak < size; ak++) {
            checkAndAddNewEmptyCompnayAtIndex(ak);
            allComInfo.get(ak).companyName = data.getString(ak);
        }
    }

    private void parseCampusDate(JSONArray data) throws JSONException {
        int size = data.length();
        for (int ak = 0; ak < size; ak++) {
            checkAndAddNewEmptyCompnayAtIndex(ak);
            allComInfo.get(ak).CampusDate = data.getString(ak);
        }
    }

    private void parseCompanyPackage(JSONArray data) throws JSONException {
        int size = data.length();
        for (int ak = 0; ak < size; ak++) {
            checkAndAddNewEmptyCompnayAtIndex(ak);
            allComInfo.get(ak).companyPackage = data.getString(ak);
        }
    }

    private void parseStatus(JSONArray data) throws JSONException {
        int size = data.length();
        for (int ak = 0; ak < size; ak++) {
            checkAndAddNewEmptyCompnayAtIndex(ak);
            allComInfo.get(ak).status = data.getString(ak);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: If you have a POJO, why not just use Gson or Jackson?

Comment: I have this .php file with me.

Comment: .php??? Put that correct json in php and use above parser or Jacson(suggested by crixxxx)

Comment: echo json_encode(array('companyName'=>$companies));
 echo json_encode(array('CampusDate'=>$campdates));
 echo json_encode(array('companyPackage'=>$packages));
 echo json_encode(array('status'=>$status));

Comment: Yup! Above code for parsing worked like charm for me,Thank you very much,but now this .PHP gives me invalid JSON. What to do with this? @Arfan Mirza.